# Default privileges are not applied after tables are created

Tags: postgresql, privileges, postgresql-11

SQL  for schema

```
CREATE SCHEMA my_schema AUTHORIZATION as_admin;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_schema TO as_user;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA my_schema TO as_admin;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_schema TO as_admin_read;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT DELETE, UPDATE, SELECT, INSERT ON TABLES TO as_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO as_admin;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO as_admin_read;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES TO as_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES TO as_admin;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO as_admin_read;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO as_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO as_admin;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO as_admin_read;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT USAGE ON TYPES TO as_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA my_schema GRANT USAGE ON TYPES TO as_admin;
```

When I create a table by a user with a group role as_admin, then privileges are not inherited

```
set role as_admin;
CREATE TABLE my_schema.test() WITH (OIDS = FALSE) TABLESPACE pg_default;
ALTER TABLE my_schema.test OWNER to as_admin;
```

SQL table after creation

```
-- Table: my_schema.test
-- DROP TABLE my_schema.test;
CREATE TABLE my_schema.test() WITH (OIDS = FALSE) TABLESPACE pg_default;
ALTER TABLE my_schema.test OWNER to as_admin;
```

Why is this happening? Where are the privileges?

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I was creating a schema as db_admin
When I recreated the schema as as_admin - all new objects were created with privileges